# What am I missing with my nginx reverse-proxy location routing setup (not routing as expected)?

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

I am testing an nginx reverse proxy setup locally using Docker. I have a bunch of docker-services that I want to proxy via my nginx service, and I've managed the front-end connection routing, but adding my backend location fails to route as expected. I am sure I am missing something about the way that nginx routes locations, but I am not sure what. I am trying to route all default requests '/' to the front-end service for UI resources and such, and that works fine, but I can't get my 'location /v1' routing to work.

I've tried:

```
location = /v1/*, 
location /v1/, 
location /v1, 
location = /v1
```

but nothing is routing the following request to the backend as expected. When it does work, it matches the frontend route and I get an html document back (routed to front-end instead of backend):
GET http://localhost/v1/status

```
events {
      worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
    }
    
    http {
    
        upstream diagnosy-frontend {
            server diagnosy-frontend:3000;
        }
    
        upstream diagnosy-backend {
            server diagnosy-backend:3001;
        }
    
        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  reverse-proxy;
    
            location = /v1/* {
                proxy_pass http://diagnosy-backend;
            }
    
            location / {
                proxy_pass http://diagnosy-frontend;
            }
        }
    }
```

experienced nginx users, what am I missing and what is a good resource for details on location rules? [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) and nor can I find location details in the [main docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/)

Comment: You can try: `location = /v1 { rewrite ^/v1/(.*) /$1  break; proxy_pass http://diagnosy-backend; proxy_pass_request_headers on; proxy_set_header Host $host; proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;}` In this case your back-end will get the part after `/v1`. Eg.: `.../v1/status/11` -> `/status/11`